# Tkinter beginner question - how to match sizes between different widgets?

Tags: python, tkinter

Question as title. I find it difficult to understand why the two widgets are different sizes, even though I have specified the same arguments. I am obviously doing something wrong - or I am forgetting something. Any help would be appreciated!

```
from tkinter import ttk
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import *


root = tk.Tk()
root.title("Tabs")
tabControl = ttk.Notebook(root)

tab1 = ttk.Frame(tabControl)
tab2 = ttk.Frame(tabControl)
tab3 = ttk.Frame(tabControl)

tabControl.add(tab1, text='tab1')
tabControl.add(tab2, text='tab2')
tabControl.add(tab3, text='tab3')
tabControl.pack(expand=1, fill="both")

canvas = Canvas(tab1, bg='white', width=100, height=100)
canvas.grid(column=0, row=5, columnspan=1, rowspan=1)

text_box = tk.Text(tab1, width=100, height=100, wrap=WORD)
text_box.grid(column=1, row=5, columnspan=1, rowspan=1)

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: You can use the ```.place``` geometry manager

Comment: For `Canvas` widget, the unit is in pixels.  But for `Text` widget, the unit for width is in characters and height in lines.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the canvas widget, the `width` and `height` are specified in pixels. For your canvas, you've choosen 100x100 *pixels*.

For the text widget, the `width` and `height` are specified in a number of characters. For your text widget you've chosen 100x100 *characters*.

Since you are using `grid`, the best way to make them the same size is to define the grid to have uniform column widths. Since the widgets are on the same row, they will both be given the same space in the vertical direction. Then, when you have the widgets fill the space they are in, they will be the same size.

```
tab1.grid_columnconfigure((0,1), uniform=1, weight=1)
tab1.grid_rowconfigure(5, weight=1)

canvas.grid(column=0, row=5, sticky="nsew")
text_box.grid(column=1, row=5, sticky="nsew")
```

Comment: I thought `height` of `Text` widget was in number of lines..? But that is also measured according to the font size I guess.

Comment: @CoolCloud: The official description is _"Specifies the desired height for the window, in units of characters in the font given by the -font option. Must be at least one."_. This is the same as the number of lines since a line can only be one character tall.